# NVM Not Working on ZSH but is on Bash - M1 Mac Mini

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, zsh, apple-m1

I followed this process for installing Node on M1 Mac Mini.

1. First I run this command to install xCode Command Line Tools:
   `sudo xcode-select --install`
2. Next I run this command to create a bash_profile:
   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash`
3. Next I run this command to install node
   `nvm install v15`

Now in both the Mac Terminal and VS Code Terminal, if I try `node -v` or `nvm -v` when using zsh I get a *command not found* response. When in bash it works fine.

Have I done something completely wrong? Or most likely, I'm missing a very obvious point?

Any assistance will be gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. For parts removed, please see the [help on chit chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working by creating a .zshrc file and pasting the following into the file `source /Users/YOUUSERNAME/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the instructions here. The NVM install on ZSH doesn't persist the path and export information.

https://gist.github.com/mike-casas/6d489bebf48d89f5109cd1395aabe150

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Apologies, I'm very new to all this.

Does it matter that I didn't install NVM via Homebrew?

Thanks

Comment: No, just put the 2 lines in your .zshrc file and restart the terminal.

Comment: I don't have homebrew installed so assume this won't work. I found a way to do it without homebrew installed too. Appreciate your help.